# Stone sink sealant

Tags: sink, sealing, stone

I have a travertine/onyx stone basin sink, its recently gotten in pretty bad shape (damage to the bow) and gets moldy spots that can't seem to die no matter how many attempts to get rid of it with multiple different chemicals.

Out of frustration I went out and bought a new sink of trionyx, which is very similar is design and look.  The instructions say that it requires regular application of a sealant in the bowl itself.  What type of sealant do I need for this?  Any recommended brands?

Comment: If the instructions do not mention a specific/recommended sealer, google finds quite a few.  Brand recommendations are not really allowed here.  Usually the main recommendation before applying sealers/paints/stuff is to make sure the surface is very clean before.  Read full instructions on the sealer.

Comment: There are many different types and kinds, don't need a specific brand but would appreciate what type would be most effective for this application